# SSRS implement Paging for tabular reports

Tags: sql-server, service, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-tablix

I am using a Tablix in one of my SQL Reporting services report. Default view shows up all records. I want to implement Paging like show up first 50 records in page 1 and next 50 records in page 2 and so on. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It helps if you tell us what you've tried so far, and what problems you ran into. (Note that you can edit your question at any time.)

Answer (score 1):

In some reports, you may want to place a page break at the end of a specified number of rows instead of, or in addition to, on groups or report items. To do this, create a group in a data region (typically a group immediately outside the detail), add a page break to the group, and then add a group expression to group by a specified number of rows.

The following expression, when placed in the group expression, assigns a number to each set of 25 rows. When a page break is defined for the group, this expression results in a page break every 25 rows.

=Int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/25)

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328(SQL.90).aspx